# Nexus N3K-C3064 SNMP ACl is not working

Tags: cisco-nx-os

I have a N3K-C3064PQ-10GX and here is my snmp configuration:

```
Community    Group / Access      context    acl_filter
_________    ______________      _______    __________
X            network-operator               ACL mapped: switch-input


IP access list switch-input
        10 permit ip 172.17.x.x/29 any
        20 deny ip any any
```

but when i tried to check open ports with nmap it shows snmp is open from everywhere, whats wrong?
Thank yu.

Comment: I'm confused by how you would "check open ports with nmap".  SNMP is essentially always UDP.  Nmap would have no ability to detect whether the switch is listening on UDP/161, since the switch will silently discard invalid packets.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have no nexus where i can test this on, but this similar forum post :

https://community.cisco.com/t5/switching/snmp-acl-on-nexus/td-p/3335165

Says to try including source, destination and protocol.

The Cisco docs also say to include source, destination and port/protocol see :

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus5000/sw/system_management/b_Cisco_Nexus_5000_Series_NX-OS_System_Management_Configuration_Guide/Cisco_Nexus_5000_Series_NX-OS_System_Management_Configuration_Guide_chapter9.html#task_D3862190751F4B1A9F5353B015A888A7

Even though these are different Nexus types, you could give it a shot.

Comment: i have many svi so i need a general way

Comment: Could you maybe include your private networks that need access to the switch, then i can try to help you create a more general ACL.

It might be enough to include the destination IP and eq SNMP

Comment: @blackmetal: That's where loopback interfaces help. Use an existing one or create one, and make sure its IP address is reachable/routeable from where you want to access it (you might want to add it's address to the dynamic rotuting protocol you are running). This brings down your SNMP ACL to just a single destination IP.